# poste.io Let's encrypt certificate issue exception

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am using the poste.io mail server.  While trying to issue the SSL cert using lets encrypt, it throws below error.  Anyone has observed it already and could fix it?

```
[2016-11-08 00:12:44] LEScript.INFO: Account already registered. Continuing.
[2016-11-08 00:12:44] LEScript.INFO: Starting certificate generation process for domains
[2016-11-08 00:12:44] LEScript.INFO: Requesting challenge for mail.domain.ltd
[2016-11-08 00:12:45] LEScript.INFO: Sending signed request to /acme/new-authz
[2016-11-08 00:12:45] LEScript.INFO: Got challenge token for mail.domain.ltd
[2016-11-08 00:12:45] LEScript.INFO: Token for mail.domain.ltd saved at /opt/www//.well-known/acme-challenge/UEyhta88fiS_E5WTn-SOxKI-lqbsK1-eTOceiE_UnTQ and should be available at http://mail.domain.ltd/.well-known/acme-challenge/UEyhta88fiS_E5WTn-SOxKI-lqbsK1-eTOceiE_UnTQ
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: Please check http://mail.domain.ltd/.well-known/acme-challenge/UEyhta88fiS_E5WTn-SOxKI-lqbsK1-eTOceiE_UnTQ - token not available
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #0 /opt/mailserver-admin/src/Analogic/LetsEncryptBundle/Handler/LeHandler.php(55): Analogic\ACME\Lescript->signDomains(Array)
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #1 /opt/mailserver-admin/src/Analogic/LetsEncryptBundle/Controller/LeController.php(74): Analogic\LetsEncryptBundle\Handler\LeHandler->renew(true)
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #2 [internal function]: Analogic\LetsEncryptBundle\Controller\LeController->issueAction(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #3 /opt/mailserver-admin/var/bootstrap.php.cache(3040): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #4 /opt/mailserver-admin/var/bootstrap.php.cache(2995): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #5 /opt/mailserver-admin/var/bootstrap.php.cache(2335): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #6 /opt/mailserver-admin/web/app.php(19): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
[2016-11-08 00:12:47] LEScript.ERROR: #7 {main}
```

Have posted in https://bitbucket.org/analogic/mailserver/issues/139/lets-encrypt-certificate-issue-exception but seems they only respond to pro customers. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  My firewall disabled the port 25.  Once the port is open, it started to work.